# Netbeans UML diagrams

Tags: netbeans, uml, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform, tool-uml

I am a beginer on UML and i am a little bit curious about netbeans tool,does it support all UML diagramm  such as class diagrams or activity diagrams and if it's not  what are the diagramms that Netbeans support? and thanks for adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1801/netbeans-uml

If you want to learn UML the good way, a better way to start can be to use a strict tool like Dia (http://dia-installer.de/) to learn the basics by doing it yourself.